# Do DFS logs contain folder permission changes?

Tags: logging, log-files, windows-event-log, dfs, dfs-r

I have a DFS server sharing files and want to see when an admin gave read/write/full control to a user in a DFS share. Is there any way I can view this?

I have checked in `C:\Windows\Debug` but the log files don't seem to show any changes made to file permissions even though I gave read access to a folder a few hours ago.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think that `C:\Windows\Debug` would contain such things, but I can assure it doesn't.

ACL changes aren't logged by DFS at all, it's just a system of pointers and replication services.

If you wanted to track such things, you'd be looking at Auditing. [This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771070.aspx) article describes how to set it up, and although it says it applies Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2, the process is the same, or very similar on other versions of Windows.

[This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/08/27/auditing-file-access-on-file-servers.aspx) article also has some great in-depth information on how it works.